# pip install is not working from git but works locally

Tags: python, git, python-3.x, pip

I had one module in the root of the project, as explained [in docs (simple example)](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/introduction.html#distutils-simple-example). It worked well for both, installed from local sources and directly from git (i mean, pip install . and pip install git+https://url/to/repository).

Now I added two new modules, also in the root of the project, so my setup now looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(name='foo',
  version='1.0',
  py_modules=['foo', 'foo1', 'foo2'],
  url='https://url/to/repository'
  )
```

Take into account that name and one of the modules are both foo.
Now I'm able to install it from sources with `pip install .` and then use it as `import foo` or `import foo1`. If I try `pip freeze` it shows foo as installed.

However, when I run `pip install git+https://url/to/repository` everything runs normally. It finishes. If I run `pip freeze`, `foo` is displayed as if it were correctly installed, but when I do `import foo` or `import foo1`, it fails.

Any idea of what is wrong? I'm using python3 and all those commands are run inside a virtualenv. I'm using bitbucket as git repository.

**UPDATE I**

Well, I created a minimal example in a public repo and it works all right from both, pip install . and pip install git+https://url/to/repo.

As far as I see, the main difference between the real repo and the foo is that foo does not have a readme, **init**.py, requirements and does not have any dependence (the real repo has some external dependencies, indicated in its setup.py as install_requires, and some modules depends on the others (as if foo1 and foo2 depends on foo)). foo project's structure is like that:

```
root
+----foo.py
+----foo1.py
+----foo2.py
+----setup.py
```

setup.py is the following:

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(name='foo',
version='2.0',
py_modules=['foo', 'foo1', 'foo2'],
url='https://bitbucket.org/idatha/test_pip/overview'
)
```

and foo, foo1 and foo2 are all the same, except for their names:

```
class foo1():
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def add(self, b):
        return self.number + b
```

**UPDATE II**

I installed again the previous working version from last commit. It worked all right. In this case, sources were copied under `.env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/foo.py` however, when I install the new version (with `foo1.py` and `foo2.py`) it does not copy anything to this directory, no mather if I install it from local source or directly from git

Comment: Hard to tell without looking at the real code and the generated package. Please provide [mcve].

Comment: I know how to create an example, I'll do it in a moment, but I don't figure out what is the general package. How do I do it?

Comment: I said "generated". :-) But it seems you haven't generate a package to install — just installed from git repo. Ok, it would be interesting to see in an example repo.

Comment: ok @phd I added more details on my minimal complete and verifiable example, hope it helps!

Comment: Ok, ok, I'm kind of doing an X-Y answer here but: If your module is called `foo`, are you sure the file `foo.py` should not be called `__main__.py`?

Comment: not sure... should it has any effect? Initialy I only had one module, so both, name and pymodule were called as foo, but now I must add two new modules (foo1 and foo2) trying not to modify foo because it is already being used as a package installed via pip, so I should not modify it

Comment: Works for me. I created a repo with `foo*.py` and `setup.py` and installed from it using `pip install git+file:///tmp/test#egg=foo`. In `site-packages` I see all those `foo*.py` and import works. The only difference is that I used `#egg=foo` to name the package. Please verify that after installation `foo*.py` are in `site-packages`.

Comment: The toy example worked for me as well, but the real one, nope. Both, with and without #egg.
I'm not sure how to check that `foo*.py` are in `site-packages`. How do I check it?

Answer (score 1):

I know I am a bit late, but I was facing the exact same issue. Apparently it turns out that when the package name does not match the repository name, I had to provide it explicitly with the `#egg=package-name` syntax (ref: https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/python/pip-install-from-git-repo-branch.html).

So in your example, you should use `pip install "git+https://bitbucket.org/idatha/test_pip/src/master/#egg=foo"` (double quotes used to escape the '=' inside a shell)